# SXC 9.1.1 Installation Error - GenerateCatalogTemplates

Tags: sitecore-commerce, sitecore-install-framework

I am getting error while installting SXC `9.1.1`. It is throwing error at `GenerateCatalogTemplates` script

Generating Catalog Templates ...
GET http://sxa.storefront.com/SiteUtilityPages/GenerateCatalogTemplates.aspx with 0-byte payload
Install-SitecoreConfiguration :

```
   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Stack Trace:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
  Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.DataProvider.CatalogRepository.GetSitecoreIdFromMappings(String entityId) +113
  Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.DataProvider.Templates.CatalogTemplateGenerator.BuildCatalogTemplates(Database database) +593
  ASP.siteutilitypages_generatecatalogtemplates_aspx.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +245
  System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +98
  System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +153
  System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4081
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While installing Sitecore 9.1.1, I have changed the default password.

While installating SXC, by changing the default password in the SXC installation pacages:

- Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.SDK.3.0.40\src\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine\wwwroot\bootstrap\Global.json
- Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.SDK.3.0.40\src\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine\wwwroot\data\Environments\PlugIn.Content.PolicySet-1.0.0.json

These changes solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

This error comes up if the certificate thumbprint is incorrect. check `Sitecore.commerce.Engine.connect.config` and `config.json(ex. C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CommerceAuthoring_Sc910\wwwroot\config.json)` file in all 4 engines

You can also check if the application pool user has permission for `SQL (commerce db)` access

Comment: Thumbprint is same on all the 4 engines config files and Sitecore.commerce.Engine.connect.config. Even application pool user is a member of role db_owner.

Comment: Please check if the certificates have permissions. Refer `https://docs.secureauth.com/display/KBA/Grant+Permission+to+Use+Signing+Certificate+Private+Key` for more details